# Interfacing with Inbuilt Fingerprint Sensor Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, fingerprint

my laptop has an inbuilt fingerprint sensor that I use with Windows Hello. I was wondering if I could use this fingerprint sensor in python. Please provide some code. Thank you. I am using Windows 10, and Python 3.8.3 64-bit version.

Edit: My laptop manufacturer is lenovo. All I want to do, is to read fingerprints, save fingerprints and compare them to stored fingerprints. My specific model is the Lenovo Ideapad Flex 14.

Comment: Does the laptop manufacturer provide Python bindings for the sensor? Is there C API for this sensor?

Comment: What is your objective to use in Python, that is more important. Once it is clear you can search for answers accordingly

Comment: I did find a C API for all windows biometrics, the Windows Biometric Framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a Github repo that is a python wrapper for the Windows Biometric Framework, which is only available for C and C++. The repo isn't perfect, as it didn't have a simple way to train and add or remove fingerprints. It checks if the fingerprint is registered with the current user's account. Anyway, I think that's the best for now. Link: https://github.com/luspock/FingerPrint

Comment: The github repo doesn't work :(